# Jeunes poulets télévisés

Tags: étymologie, alimentation, dialectes, afrique

Au Burkina Faso, de nombreux commerces se spécialisent dans les **Jeunes Poulets Télévisés**.
Il vendent des poulets cuits à la broche.

**QUESTION:** Quelle est l’étymologie réelle de "télévisé" dans ce contexte ?

Après quelques recherches sur Internet, il apparaît que diverses théories ont été émises: à manger en face de la télévision, cuits dans un appareil qui ressemble à une télévision, etc.

[image: Jeunes Poulets Télévisés]

Comment: Quesiton super intéressante, et dont la réponse nécessite autre chose qu'une simple recherche Google. Je suis curieux de savoir.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Le site d'office du tourisme du Burkina Faso](http://www.ontb.bf/index.php/visiter/art-de-vivre/gastronomie):

> Le poulet ‘’bicyclette’’: véritable poulet de brousse est ainsi appelé parce qu’il a de longues pattes et lorsqu’il court, on dirait qu’il pédale. Il est grillé sur de la braise, ou rôti dans un grand gril verticale dont la porte est vitrée : on l’appelle poulet ‘’télévisé’’ .

Ainsi le poulet est cuit derrière une vitre et cela rappelle la télévision.

---

[Le 6e et 7e résultat de la recherche google](https://www.google.de/search?q=Jeunes%20Poulets%20T%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=NfGoVYK9MqTvywPig6GwCQ) donne un [blog](http://uneparisienneaouaga.tumblr.com/post/35077135058/ya-pas-de-probleme) qui explique :

> C'est quoi les poulets télévisés? Bon (comme ils disent ici) c'est des **poulets dans une vitrine, tu vois, comme la télévision quoi!?** En fait c'est une rôtissoire toute bête mais c'est vrai que mettre un poulet dans une boîte avec vitre d'où tu peux le regarder tourner, bon bah c'est un peu comme la télé quoi!

Comment: J'ai trouvé pas mal de blogs avançant diverses théories. Ai-je une raison particulière de faire confiance à ce blog plutôt qu'à un autre ? Un article de journal (ou un document académique, ou un dictionnaire un peu sérieux) serait idéal.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Celui-ci ne fonde pas sa théorie sur des suppositions mais rapporte un échange avec un habitant.

Comment: L'office du tourisme est une source plus fiable, merci ! "lorsqu’il court, on dirait qu’il pédale" <- Cela contredit l'article de *Jeune Afrique* cité par Gilles, mais c'est un autre débat :-)

Answer (score 5):

Une recherche sur [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&btnG=Chercher+des+livres&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=fr) donne plusieurs sources, dont la plus ancienne explique l'étymologie.

- [Louis-Jean Calvet. Article indéterminé. *In* Le Français dans le monde. 1987.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eZBcAAAAMAAJ&q=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&dq=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCGoVChMIkvX295XjxgIVjFsUCh1tSw5y)

  > Thérèse Dalhoutre, une collègue qui enseigne à l'université de Niamey, me signale en effet qu'elle a vu à Ouagadougou, au Burkina Faso, un restaurant proposant à ses clients des *jeunes poulets télévisés*. L'expression pourrait laisser perplexe, mais elle parle mieux à l'œil qu'à l'oreille. Imaginez en effet ces fours de dimension réduite dont la porte de verre permet de voir à l'intérieur le volatile tournant sur sa broche : tout y est, le format d'un téléviseur, le spectacle à l'intérieur, et le jeune poulet ainsi télévisé présente en outre sur bien des programmes l'avantage d'être, lui, digeste.

Par complétude, voici l'intégralité des autres documents trouvés par cette recherche qui proposent une étymologie. On constate qu'il n'y a pas de voix dissonante.

- [Jeune Afrique. Article non déterminé. 1994.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=j_7xAAAAMAAJ&q=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&dq=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBGoVChMIkvX295XjxgIVjFsUCh1tSw5y)

  > Les marchands proposent aux chalands leurs « poulets bicyclette », ainsi nommés parce que, cuits, ils ont les pattes en l'air comme pour un dernier sprint, et leurs « poulets télévisés », derrière la vitre de rôtissoires électriques.
- Article non déterminé. *In* [Le monde francophone en Afrique : actes du X<sup>ème</sup> Colloque international francophone organisé à Ouagadougou, Manega et Ziniaré. 2000.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=82pJAAAAYAAJ&q=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&dq=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CEgQ6AEwB2oVChMIkvX295XjxgIVjFsUCh1tSw5y)

  > À ras de ce sol trop stérile poussent les innombrables étals et échoppes du petit commerce burkinabé : mini-quincailleries, super-poulets télévisés derrière la vitre du tourne-broche, [...]
- [Stéphanie Jouan. *Chroniques de Koudougou*, Burkina Faso. 2007.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=4hlrDaHcWyMC&pg=PA21&dq=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIkvX295XjxgIVjFsUCh1tSw5y#v=onepage&q=%22poulets%20t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&f=false)

  > on rôtit des poulets (les fameux poulets "télévisés" parce qu'on les voit à travers le four...)
- [Serge Latouche. *Entre mondialisation et décroissance : l'autre Afrique*. 2008.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=BFwUAQAAIAAJ&q=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&dq=%22poulets+t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9s%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBWoVChMIkvX295XjxgIVjFsUCh1tSw5y)

  > De pittoresques enseignes peintes de couleurs vives annoncent les échoppes les plus diverses : jeunes poulets télévisés (cuits à la broche derrière une vitre), [...]