# What are some differences between the French spoken in l'Afrique Noire and the French spoken in France?

Tags: régionalismes, afrique

I am a Spanish speaker, and last week I traveled abroad to a summer camp where I met people of different nationalities, among them several hispanophones. There were several words specific to each of our countries, and I was wondering (because I am interested in French) what are some words that countries like Senegal or Côte d'Ivoire use that are not used in France?

Comment: See also [this](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/14436), and also generally the [tag:afrique] tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J'ai passé deux ans au Cameroun et ils ont beaucoup d'expressions (plutôt que des mots) qui sont peu comprises en France. J'en ai citée quelques'unes ci-dessous :

> **C'est comment** ? = Comment ça va ?
>
> Mon téléphone est **gâté**. = Mon téléphone est en panne.
>
> **Assiah** ! = Je suis désolé pour toi.
>
> **On est ensemble**. = Au revoir.
>
> Je t'attends **dePUIS** ! = Ca fait longtemps que je t'attends !
>
> On a mangé **jusqu'ààààà** ! = On a beaucoup mangé !
>
> **C'est que même quoi ça ? / C'est quoi même** ? = Qu'est-ce que c'est que ça ?
>
> **Mouf** !!! (très vulgaire)= Va t'en / Casse-toi !!!
>
> Pardon, **massa** ! = Pardon, monsieur !

Au République du Congo, où j'ai aussi vécu, il existe moins d'expressions et de mots uniques (du moins en français) à leur pays puisque la plupart des gens se parlent (hors l'école) en une autre langue: le kikongo, lingala, ou lari, par exemple.

Answer (score 1):

[Le rap](http://www.afrik.com/l-argot-africain-inspire-la-langue-francaise) offre une grande variété d'expressions spécifiques au *rap* que peu de français connaissent (ou comprennent) vraiment.

L'[argot ivoirien](http://panafricanisme.com/cote-ivoire-argot-ivoirien-le-nouchi/335/) n'est pas utilisé en France, et peu des expressions citées peuvent être devinées par un français.